# How do we get rid of error 13 permission denied error during openstack image create?

Tags: openstack, microstack

microstack.openstack image create --file filename.qcow2 --disk-format qcow2 "imagename"

This gives error as

[Error 13] Permission denied file path

Comment: Where are your images stored (check the glance config file) and who owns that directory?

Answer (score 5):

I had the same error. The image file was in the downloads folder. The work around for me was to put the image in the folder microstack had access to. I copied the file image to `/var/snap/microstack/common/images/`. The cirros file that comes with microstack is also in that folder.

After copying the file, the image create was successful.

Comment: And remember to give the full path as microstack.openstack image create --file /var/snap/microstack/common/images/name_of_image name